# How to download images not from directed URL

Tags: android, image

With `Android Studio` I want to download the `images` from a `URL` , I mean that these `images` are in this URL. I have the code but it's for direct download of them.
I must show them in a `Custom ListView`.
This is the code:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.enclosure);
    try {
        URL url = new URL("MY_URL"); <-- the URL where I want to get the images in enclosures
        HttpGet httpRequest = null;

        httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                .execute(httpRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
        InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

Before I had this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.enclosure);
img.setImageDrawable(web.get(position).getEnclosure());
```

but the `images` weren't displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is trying to decode the input stream of the entire page, which wouldn't work because the page is not just an image; there is text and such as well. This wouldn't work. You have to get the URL of each of the images you want to download, and then download those images separately.

Comment: So first I have to get the Strings of the URL images , and then download them by the stringe I got

Comment: Scuse me for the disorder but nobody could answer me in another question, could you do it?
Since I have to take the `strings` of these `URLs` I created another `TextView` and then in place of `URL url = new URL("MY_URL");` I put `URL url = new URL(context.getString(R.id.my_new_textview));` . Is this correct? Because the images aren't displayed.

Comment: Why are you trying to display an image in a TextView? What you put will only display... Well, I'm not sure what. Your resource points to an ID so I don't know what would happen. Anyway, first thing is first: you need to be using an ImageView. That's a fundamental concept you need to know.

Comment: I'm still using the code I have above but only where is `URL url = new URL("MY_URL");` I put `URL url = new URL(context.getString(R.id.my_new_textview));` because to display `images` the `ImageView` has to refer to a `URL`. Am I wrong? What else would I do if not?